# Azure deploy from Github broke

Tags: azure, web-deployment

I've been deploying from archive to Azure for a while. All of a sudden it stopped working. I can still build locally and on AppVeyor's CI. I finally gave up and Web deployed from Visual Studio. Site is working just fine. There's not much I can find on how to fix this. There also does not seem to be a way to remove the deployment slot from the Azure web site. Sure would like to get deployment from source control working again.

Here's the log.

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
  Restoring NuGet packages...
  To prevent NuGet from downloading packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'.
  All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(983,5): warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [D:\home\site\repository\Mike-Ward.Net\Mike-Ward.Net.csproj]
  No way to resolve conflict between "System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes" and "System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089". Choosing "System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes" arbitrarily.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Drawing.Design, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing.Design\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.Design.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.Design.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "mscorlib, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "2.0.5.0" [] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\\mscorlib.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "2.0.5.0" [] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Data, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.RegularExpressions, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Accessibility, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.ServiceProcess, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceProcess\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.ServiceProcess.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceProcess\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.ServiceProcess.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Security, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Windows.Forms, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Drawing, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Configuration, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Data.OracleClient, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data.OracleClient\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Core, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "3.5.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Configuration.Install, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration.Install\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.Install.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration.Install\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.Install.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Runtime.Remoting, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Remoting\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Remoting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Data.SqlXml, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlXml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.SqlXml.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.SqlXml.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.EnterpriseServices, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.Services, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Transactions, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.Transactions\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.DirectoryServices, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.DirectoryServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.DirectoryServices.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.DirectoryServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.DirectoryServices.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Xml, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.DirectoryServices.Protocols\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.DirectoryServices.Protocols\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Deployment, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Deployment\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Deployment.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Deployment\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Deployment.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Design, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Design.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Design.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. [D:\home\site\repository\Mike-Ward.Net\Mike-Ward.Net.csproj]
D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\\mscorlib.dll", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project. [D:\home\site\repository\Mike-Ward.Net\Mike-Ward.Net.csproj]
D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Web", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project. [D:\home\site\repository\Mike-Ward.Net\Mike-Ward.Net.csproj]
  Mike-Ward.Net -> D:\home\site\repository\Mike-Ward.Net\bin\Mike-Ward.Net.dll
  Transformed Web.config using D:\home\site\repository\Mike-Ward.Net\Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
  Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
  C:\DWASFiles\Sites\~1mike-ward\Temp\4dd11e9b-bd18-4b2e-92cd-533162fd326e.
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2987,5): error : Copying file cdn\images\blog\VistaWeatherGadgetUpdated_108DB\image_4.png to C:\DWASFiles\Sites\~1mike-ward\Temp\4dd11e9b-bd18-4b2e-92cd-533162fd326e\cdn\images\blog\VistaWeatherGadgetUpdated_108DB\image_4.png failed. Could not find file 'cdn\images\blog\VistaWeatherGadgetUpdated_108DB\image_4.png'. [D:\home\site\repository\Mike-Ward.Net\Mike-Ward.Net.csproj]
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\repository\Mike-Ward.Net\Mike-Ward.Net.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="C:\DWASFiles\Sites\~1mike-ward\Temp\4dd11e9b-bd18-4b2e-92cd-533162fd326e";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release /p:SolutionDir="D:\home\site\repository\.\\"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.

... rest is restore from the previous deployment.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error, I'd guess that you forgot to add `cdn\images\blog\VistaWeatherGadgetUpdated_108DB\image_4.png` to your repo. Please see [this page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Make-sure-all-your-files-are-committed) for advice on investigating this kind of issues.

Comment: I can see it clear as day now. I got distracted with all the .NET framework messages and thought that had to be the problem. Thanks.